# Hazelcast: force map to load

Tags: persistence, lazy-loading, hazelcast

I'm looking for a way to force map initialization. I'm using Spring integration and MapStore implementation and I noticed that before business logic tries to touch a map they are not initialized, i.e. loadKeys() method is not called and even no map exists under the category. Is there a property to make maps non-lazy? Or an API to call initialization?

Comment: Why don't you just call map.size() or map.get("some random key") to initialize it?

Comment: Thank you, I tried both of this and it seems it takes no affect. Using  a non-random key cases entry loading from DB to the map and it works perfectly, but it failed to force call of loadAllKeys() method on startup. It is connected to 'storage' node with persistence set up by 'lite' client that tries to update the map.

Comment: which version are you using for hazelcast?  were you able to get this to work through eager mode or some other way?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.EAGER);

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked using myMap.values()

Comment: which version of hazelcast did you try?

Comment: it was 3.1 or 3.2 as I recall